# Newest Quarkus version (2.6.3) reactive messaging error

Tags: quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I recently upgraded to the newest Quarkus version and seem to be having some issues with the configuration of Smallrye's reactive messaging. Prior to 2.6.3, the connector has always been **smallrye-kafka**, but it seems I am having a strange error now when I run my application in that it cannot identify that as a known Kafka connector?

Error:

```
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#generateResources threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Found 2 deployment problems: 
[1] The channel 'kafka-data' is configured with an unknown connector (smallrye-kafka)
[2] The channel 'dlq-data' is configured with an unknown connector (smallrye-kafka)
```

This is my configuration (real values omitted for demonstration purposes):

```
mp:
  messaging:
    incoming:
      dlq-data:
        health-topic-verification-enabled: true
        connector: smallrye-kafka
        topic: ${kafka.topic.dlq}
        failure-strategy: ignore
        broadcast: true
        value:
          deserializer: myOwnCustomDeserializer
        auto:
          offset:
            reset: earliest
        enable:
          auto:
            commit: false
        group:
          id: someGroupID
      kafka-data:
        health-topic-verification-enabled: true
        connector: smallrye-kafka
        topic: ${kafka.topic.fulfillment}
        failure-strategy: dead-letter-queue
        dead-letter-queue:
          topic: ${kafka.topic.dlq}
          value:
            serializer: io.quarkus.kafka.client.serialization.ObjectMapperSerializer
        broadcast: true
        value:
          deserializer: myOwnCustomDeserializer
        auto:
          offset:
            reset: earliest
        enable:
          auto:
            commit: false
        group:
          id: someGroupId
```

The only thing I can gather from the official documentation is that some reactive messaging packages were split but there is no mention about this connector changing (seeing that I'm sure it did not change).

Comment: Can you verify that the connector extension is in the classpath?

Comment: Thanks Clement, the issue was with me not including the right reactive-messaging package after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, make sure you have the connector you want to use in the classpath. If you are using Quarkus, there are "extensions" for the connectors.

For Kafka, use:

```xml
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```